# perl accelerator?

Tags: apache-2.2, perl, mod-perl

what is the best accelerator for Perl website?

Comment: Sorry, no answer for you until you start to participate in the site as something other than a leech.

Answer (score 1):

I assume, since you just said "Perl" & didn't give any additional information, that you're running on some kind of Unix-like system.
In that case my suggestion would be [mod_perl](http://perl.apache.org) (per the tag I added).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps mod_perl

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Perl doesn't need much acceleration - internally it works very differently from Java or PHP.

But if you're invoking perl using CGI, then you've got a big overhead there which you need to address (use mod_perl or fastCGI) befoer the code gets to the Perl runtime binary.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best acceleration for Perl website is using one of Perl frameworks to build one.
You may want to see at Catalyst, Mojolicious or Dancer - they looks to be in top now and have good community support.

If your site still runs in CGI it's maybe time to rebuild it in modern (and much faster) way?